# Checking to see if rsync was successful

Tags: shell-script, rsync, exit-status

Is it possible to check if an rsync is successful and potentially collect an error if its not?

As I am using --link-dest, I think this may be harder to detect.

I'm fairly new to bash, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is a slimmed down version of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

site_host=(
    "site1@grid.co.uk"
    "site2@grid.co.uk"  
)

backup_dest=(
    "/Users/computername/Desktop/rsync/test1.co.uk"
    "/Users/computername/Desktop/rsync/test2.co.uk"
)

now=`date "+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"`
today=`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`
yesterday=`date -v -1d +"%d-%m-%Y"`

log="/Users/computername/Desktop/rsync/rsync.log"

site_count=${#site_host[@]}

for (( i = 0; i < site_count; i++ )); do

    site_source="${site_host[$i]}:~/public_html"
    site_dest="${backup_dest[$i]}/$today/"

    rsync -zavx -e 'ssh -p22' \
            --numeric-ids \
            --delete -r \
            --link-dest=../$yesterday $site_source $site_dest

    echo "$now - File Backup Completed - ${backup_dest[$i]}/$today" >> $log 

done
```

Updated:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

site_host=(
    "site1@grid.co.uk"
    "site2@grid.co.uk"  
)

backup_dest=(
    "/Users/computername/Desktop/rsync/test1.co.uk"
    "/Users/computername/Desktop/rsync/test2.co.uk"
)

now=`date "+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"`
today=`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`
yesterday=`date -v -1d +"%d-%m-%Y"`

log="/Users/computername/Desktop/rsync/rsync.log"

site_count=${#site_host[@]}

for (( i = 0; i < site_count; i++ )); do

    site_source="${site_host[$i]}:~/public_html"
    site_dest="${backup_dest[$i]}/$today/"

    failures=0

    if  rsync -zavx -e 'ssh -p22' \
            --numeric-ids \
            --delete -r \
            --link-dest=../$yesterday $site_source $site_dest;
    then

        echo "$now - File Backup Completed - ${backup_dest[$i]}/$today" >> $log 

    else

        echo "$now - File Backup Failed - ${backup_dest[$i]}/$today" >> $log 
        failures=$((failures+1))

    fi

    if ((failures != 0)); then exit 1; fi 

done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like most programs, rsync returns a nonzero status if an error occurs. Since you have `set -e` at the top of the script, your script will exit with a nonzero status if rsync does.

If you want to do some recovery if rsync fails, you can keep going and analyze the status. With `set -e`, you need to put the rsync command in a conditional so that the script doesn't exit.

```
failures=0
…
  if rsync …; then
    echo "rsync succeeded"
  else
    echo "rsync failed"
    failures=$((failures+1))
  fi
…
if ((failures != 0)); then exit 1; fi
```

If you want to analyze the status code, a common idiom is `status=0; rsync … || status=$?`: this command always returns a success status since the command on the right-hand side of the `||` operator always succeeds, and `status` will be set to the status of the rsync command.

```
  status=0
  rsync … || status=$?
  if ((status != 0)); then
    …
  fi
```

Comment: Thanks Giles. Where you add ... in 'if rsync …; then', what does this refer to?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized! I have added an updated version of my code. Is this correct?

Comment: @ccdavies The point of counting failures was if you were going to run the whole loop all the time, and exit at the end if there was at least one failure. Your code is correct, but overly complicated for what it does.